# Why does this toggler function not work in Jquery 1.8.3 (but works in 1.8.2)

Tags: jquery

I have had this script (and HTML) on a site with no problems when loading Jquery 1.8.2 - but a different plugin needs version 1.8.3 - and now the function does not work anymore. I suspect it has to do with the .parent and .children part of the code (?) but I am not sure. Could anyone tell me how to get this script working with 1.8.3 or later?

HTML:

```
<div class='toggle_parent'>

  <div class='toggled_content' style='display:none;'>
      My Content
  </div>
    <div class='toggleHolder'>
    <span class='toggler'>Open</span>
    <span class='toggler' style='display:none;'>Close</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.toggler').live('click',function(){
      $(this).parent().children().toggle();  //swaps the display:none between the two spans
      $(this).parent().parent().find('.toggled_content').slideToggle();  //swap the display of the main content with slide action

  });

});
```

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UezUj/363/

(I need the script to look for a toogle div in the surrounding divs only, and can't use #id for targeting the div's - since I will have many toggles next to each other and don't want them all to open at the same time. Hope that makes sense...)

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `on` instead of `live`?

Comment: I just pasted your code in a JSBIN here: http://jsbin.com/elodex/1/ and it works fine! Are you sure your jquery is loaded correctly? Are you trying to load two jqueries at the same time?

Comment: @TylerCrompton To be honest I have no idea! The danger of copy and pasting. I am not a coder - just pretending from time to time...

Comment: @limelights - thanks, that is really useful. I could not find the 1.8.3 option in the JS fiddle. (Only the edge version )

Comment: @AndersCarlén Nemas problemas or as we say in Sweden, coola bananer!

Comment: @AndersCarlén, `live` has been deprecated since 1.7 in favor or `on`.

Comment: @TylerCrompton: Aha! Thanks! Will change.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the update:

1. There is nothing wrong with the code snippet in the question (as limelights pointed out first!)
2. My problems were caused by a plugin loading a customized version of Jquery which did not have all the necessary functions for this script.

Once that was sorted out - it all works again. Thanks to TylerCrompton the snippet has even been improved a little bit, so it wasn't all for nothing!
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$('.toggler').live('click', function(){ /*content*/ };
```

with

```
$('.toggler').click(function(){ /*content*/ };
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bkqsS/ (tried with jQuery 1.9.0).